# Run WiX EXE CustomAction from TempFolder

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix3.5

I'm using WiX 3.5 for the following.

I have some files (an EXE and DLL) that I need to extract to the TEMP folder at the beginning of the installation (before the EULA is displayed), then run the EXE. I have the part working that extracts the files, using http://msiext.codeplex.com/. The code looks like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetBinaryWrite_TargetFileName_1" Property="BINARYWRITE_TARGETFILENAME" Value="[TempFolder]ActivationUtility.exe" />
```

Notice that [TempFolder] is used and (on Windows 7) resolves to "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\", and this is not "set up" anywhere in my WXS files - it's a Windows property, like ProgramFilesFolder, etc...

I set up my EXE CustomAction like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="ActivationUtility"
                  Directory="TempFolder"
                  ExeCommand="ActivationUtility.exe"
                  Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
```

The linker then complains: error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Directory:TempFolder'. If I use "[TempFolder]", the compiler complains. Why does this property work for one CustomAction, but not another? What exactly do I need to do to reference the TempFolder for the above CustomAction?

Comment: is it because of the session id? https://serverfault.com/questions/1035959/windows-server-2019-windows-installer-temp-path-session-id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code compiles for me (can't test it right now)

Add this under your root directoy

```
<Directory Id="TempTest" FileSource="[TempFolder]"></Directory>
```

And declare the custom action like this

```
<CustomAction Id="ActivationUtility"
              Directory="TempTest"
              ExeCommand="ActivationUtility.exe"
              Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
```

You can of course change the id of your folder

Comment: Thanks - I finally figured that out, although I still don't understand why they didn't just make [TempFolder] work at Directory=.

Comment: Using [TempFolder] copies files to the root of my H:/ drive (why?) and then fails to execute with the error " ********** Info 1721.There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: SetProcessEXE_Cmd, location: H:\, command: ********** "

Comment: @rolls you are better off opening a new question. The Information given isn't really enough to answer your question, let alone via comments. :)